# Angular2: custom validator with two parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I try to customize validator for my form. Validator has two parameters: the first parameter is quantity of digits before point and the second - is quantity of digits after point. And I use these parameters to make a regexp:

```
new RegExp('^[0-9]{0,' + a + '}([,][0-9]{0,' + b + '})?$')
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/v4sWLGRHFijvQH6DfRPa?p=preview

But form still doesn't work correctly, message doesn't show if I don't follow regexp while typing into input. And I have no idea how I can use two parameters to validate template driven form using directive.

Help please

Comment: From a quick look at the plunkr, I don't think your custom validator directive is being declared in the app module, so it won't be getting picked up on the form.
Also you are only passing a single parameter - '16,6' to the validator which is fine - looks like those values aren't being parsed correctly?
You might also consider just using the regex with the built-in `pattern` validator directly rather than a custom option.

Answer (score 1):

you have `@Input` and not `@Input()` in your custom-input.component, so just add the `()` and it'll work fine. so it'd be:

`//Placeholders for the callbacks which are later provided
    //by the Control Value Accessor
    private onTouchedCallback: () => void = noop;
    private onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = noop;
    @Input() inputPattern;
    //get accessor`